# I can not run the method in the background in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a service DocumentServiceImpl.

In it I want to run a method `index()` of `class GlobalSearch` in background.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService { 

... any code

@Transactional
 public void save(){

...

  Thread indexTread = new Thread(new GlobalSearch(file, id), "GlobalSearch");
  indexTread.start();

....

 }

}
```

Method `index` of class GlobalSearch using method from class ExtractTextFromFile. I inject class ExtractTextFromFile using constructor and Lombok annotation @RequiredArgsConstructor

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class GlobalSearch implements Runnable{
 public final ExtractTextFromFile extractTextFromFile; (41 lines)

 public File file;
 public Long id;
 public GlobalSearch(File File, Long id){
    this.file = file;
    this.id = id;
}

public void index(File file, Long id) {
    File textFile = extractTextFromFile.toText(file, id);

 ... code of this method

}

@Override
public void run() {
    index(file, id);
}

...other methods
public void search(){...}
public String delete(){...}

}
```

.. but IDE gives `Variable 'extractTextFromFile' might not have been initialize` for `public final ExtractTextFromFile extractTextFromFile;`

If i inject using:

```
@Autowired
ExtractTextFromFile extractTextFromFile;
```

Then it gives error:

```
Exception in thread "GlobalSearch" java.lang.NullPointerException
at bps.module.zxc.component.GlobalSearch.index(GlobalSearch.java:41)
at bps.module.zxc.component.GlobalSearch.run(GlobalSearch.java:136)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This class ExtractTextFromFile:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class ExtractTextFromFile {
 public File toText(File file, Long id) {
  extractFromPfd();
  extractFromWord();
 }
  extractFromPfd(){...};
  extractFromWord(){...};
 }
```

Comment: In one case, you're trying to use a field without initializing it. In the second case, you expect Spring to autowire a bean inside an object that is created by yourself, using new, and not by Spring. A simple solution is to autowire the bean inside your DocumentServiceImpl, and to pass it as argument to your GlobalSearch constructor.

Comment: it works, thanks, but i wanted the method toText from  class ExtractTextFromFile to run in the background.

Comment: It does, since it's called by index() which is called by run(), which is the runnable passed to the thread constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, i removed annotation @Component of classes GlobalSearch and ExtractTextFromFile then i initialised them as simple clases with

```
 GlobalSearch globalSearch = new GlobalSearch()
```

...and

```
 ExtractTextFromFile extractTextFromFile = new ExtractTextFromFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you try @asyc over the method and @EnableAsyc**

```
@Async
     public void looper()
     {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<20000;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("hitting "+i);
        }
     }
```

**Use @EnableAsync over configurations**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class SpringbootdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootdemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```